# C++ Code Autoformatting

Tags: c++, linux, gedit

After years of using Visual Studio for C++ programming, I am just now making the switch to linux for work. Everything is going great so far with one minor exception - gedit. After writing some code in a basic text editor, I am really starting to miss the auto formatting features that I have grown accustomed to.

Is there some type of "programmer's notepad" which would help with on-the-fly auto formatting or would I have to use a standard IDE for this functionality? Do most linux developers format their code manually using a basic text editor?

I am not looking for a full blown IDE, just something that will automatically format my C++ code as I type.

Comment: astyle comes to mind, but it formats a given file

Comment: I use eclipse + CDT http://eclipse.org

Comment: Clang-format is nice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a pretty wide spectrum of text editors to IDEs on Linux. Here are a few that come to mind, from most "notepad-like" to most "VS-like".

In the "text editor" department (meaning no integrated compilation, build configs, debugger, etc.. just editing text / code):

- **gedit** (most basic notepad-like app, IMO)
- **Kate** (enhanced notepad but without "commands", and with nice auto-formatting and highlighting)
- **Emacs** (enhanced notepad, with commands and advanced options, can be hard to use)
- **VIM** (same category as emacs, can be hard to use, I don't like it)
- **Sublime-text** (cool enhanced text editor, lots of neat features, but also a bit hard to master)

In the IDE department (meaning some build tools integration, and usually some code-completion and semantics analysis of code (detect variables, classes, etc.., can link to dox for them)):

- **Geany** (lightweight IDE, not much more than an enhanced text editor with a "build" button)
- **NetBeans** (average-sized IDE, quality is so-so, IMO)
- **Eclipse** (average-sized IDE, easy to use, i.e., good for small projects, e.g., school assignments)
- **Qt Creator** (average-to-large IDE, mainly aimed at working with Qt)
- **Code::Blocks** (average-sized IDE, quality is so-so but OK, IMO)
- **KDevelop** (an IDE a bit on the heavy side, but great features overall, and has the best code completion I have ever seen, beats Intellisense for C++ like a rented mule)

Of course, this is just a partial list, including only those I've been exposed to or have heard a lot about. There are probably many others out there.

> Is there some type of "programmer's notepad" which would help with on-the-fly auto formatting or would I have to use a standard IDE for this functionality?

All the applications I've listed above in the "text editor" department all support this kind of feature (but I'm not 100% sure on Gedit, because it's kind of basic and I don't use it much, cause I don't like it). The only main jump you get as far as writing code from a text editor to an IDE is the code-completion / background-parser, i.e., the "Intellisense" type of features, including tooltip documentation on classes or functions. You cannot get that in a text editor because it would have to be aware of your build configuration (e.g., your cmake files or equivalent) to know where to pull headers from to be able to "understand" your code beyond trivial syntax rules, keywords and indentation.

> Do most linux developers format their code manually using a basic text editor?

No. But it's a diverse world. Some like basic text editors where auto-indentation is about as much as you get, while others prefer feature-rich IDEs, and then, there are those who choose their text editor by how cool-looking the color themes are. ;)

And btw, there are also pretty powerful command-line code formatters, like **clang-format**, which can re-format your code in a much smarter way because it has an actual full-blown C++ compiler front-end parsing your code.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, **gedit** have auto indent support, Try Edit -> Preferences -> Editor  and check "Enable automatic indentation".

However, personally, I recommend you to use [VIM](http://www.vim.org/index.php), a professional text editor, although is not for everybody. Vim is not an IDE, just a text editor, but it's very powerful.

If **vim** seems too much by the moment, I think that **kate** is better than **gedit**.

Comment: I would recommend `emacs` instead of `vim` but it is a matter of taste.

Comment: Yeah. I know `emacs` is great too, but I'm used to `vim`.